# deleting a call recording from twilio in node.js

Tags: node.js, twilio

How can I delete a call recording from twilio using the npm module ?

I am trying to use the request module like this:

```
request.del(recording_url, {
  'auth': {
    'user': accountSid,
    'pass': authToken
  }
}, function (err, done){
  if(err){
    console.log("error deleting from twilio", err)
  } else {
    console.log("removed from twilio", done);
  }
});
```

I am getting the following info in the `done` object:

```
body: '<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'?>\n<TwilioResponse><RestException><Code>20004</Code><Message>Method not allowed</Message><MoreInfo>https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20004</MoreInfo><Status>405</Status></RestException></TwilioResponse>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

If you are using the Twilio node library you use this code to delete a recording resource:

```
var accountSid = 'AC3137d76457814a5eabf7de62f346d39a';
var authToken = "{{ auth_token }}";
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.recordings("RE557ce644e5ab84fa21cc21112e22c485").delete(function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err.status);
        throw err.message;
    } else {
        console.log("Sid RE557ce644e5ab84fa21cc21112e22c485 deleted successfully.");
    }
});
```

Check out the [Recordings](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/recording) resource documentation for more info, specifically this example on [deleting recordings](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/recording#instance-delete-examples).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yup found the docs soon after posting the question. Thanks. This works.